# Sufficient conditions for three degree sequences to be $3$-uniform hypergraphic

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Recently I learned that the Gale Ryser Theorem provides sufficient and necessary conditions for a pair of sequences of non-negative integers to be bipartite graphic. That is:

A pair of sequences of non-negative integers $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and $(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ is bigraphic if and only if
${\displaystyle \sum _{i=1}^{n}a_{i}=\sum _{i=1}^{n}b_{i}}$ and the following inequality holds for all
$k \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$:
$\Sigma_{i=1}^k a_i \le \Sigma_{i=1}^n min(b_i,k)$.

I am wondering if there also exists a theorem providing sufficient conditions for 3 sequences of non-negative integers $(a_1,\ldots ,a_n),(b_1,\ldots,b_n),(c_1,\ldots,c_n)$ to be tripartite graphic.

Comment: You should also use the terms "bipartite and tripartite graphs".

Comment: @JeanMarie Those are different questions. The clearest difference is that for a tripartite graph on $n+n+n$ vertices, the maximum degree possible is $2n$, while for a $3$-uniform tripartite hypergraph on $n+n+n$ vertices, the degree can go as high as $n^2$.